# How can I check that a form field prefilled isn't null using capybara?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

i want check this field, is it the value is null or not?

`<input name='phone_number' type='text'>`

i have try

`expect(@browser.phone_number.value.to_s).exist`
`expect(@browser.phone_number.value).exist`
`expect(@browser.phone_number.value).be_truthy`
`expect(@browser.phone_number).exist`
`expect(@browser.phone_number).to be_truthy`
`expect(@browser.phone_number).to exist`

but it isn't error when value of the field is null

i want scenario passed when value is not null
and error when value is null

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what `@browser` and `phone_number` are but I'm going to assume they're from a page object model using something like SitePrism.

When not using a page object model this would be exactly what the `:with` option of the `:field` selector is for.  It can take a regex or a string to match the current field value against.  Therefore we can check for a field with name of 'phone_number' and a value that has at least one character with

```
expect(page).to have_field('phone_number', with: /.+/)
```

How you use that option with a page object model depends on exactly how you've implemented the page object model, but it usually boils down to the implementation finally calling `find` with the `:field` selector type and the options above.  If using `SitePrism` that would mean

```
class MyPage < SitePrism::Page
  ...
  element :phone_number, :field, 'phone_number' # define phone_number to use the 'field' selector type
end

@browser = MyPage.new
expect(@browser).to have_phone_number(with: /.+/)
```